# rounding numbers

Tags: php

Helllo,

I need to do some how to get this:

2.1 = 3

2.2 = 3

2.5 = 3

2.8 = 3

2.9999 = 3

I tried:

```
Number: 2.1
round(2.1, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) //2
round(2.1, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP) //2
round(2.1, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN) // 2
round(2.1, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD) // 2
ceil(2.1) // 3
Number: 2.5
round(2.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) //2
round(2.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP) //3
round(2.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN) // 2
round(2.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD) // 3
ceil(2.5) // 3
Number: 2.6
round(2.6, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) //3
round(2.6, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP) //3
round(2.6, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN) // 3
round(2.6, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD) // 3
ceil(2.6) // 3
Number: 2.99
round(2.99, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) //3
round(2.99, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP) //3
round(2.99, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN) // 3
round(2.99, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD) // 3
ceil(2.99) // 3
```

How I can do this?

Comment: Using the [ceil()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) function, what's the problem?

Comment: So why `ceil` not suits?

Answer (score 3):

Returns the next highest integer value by rounding up value if necessary.

```
ceil ( float $value )
```